# same column on different tables - how to?

Tags: database, google-appsheet

I am very new on Appsheet, I am have the same variable "Client name" on 3 tables on appSheet DB, then I need to use the same client name on 2 pages of my app, but one of them is a grouped version of the client because there might be n rows for the same client name, how can I proceed?

For now they're working independently :(